# UIWebView download different url depending on device language

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have localised hybrid iOS development, the UIWebView will download from different url according to user's default language, the code is shown below. but I have some problem, when test in Chinese simplified environment, the UIWebView is still downloading the english, please help. Thanks.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *urlString = nil;
NSString *languageCode = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
if ([languageCode isEqualToString:@"zh-Hans"]) {
    urlString = @"http://www.worldbellydancefestival.com/WBDF-contact-cn";
}if ([languageCode isEqualToString:@"zh-Hant"]) {
    urlString = @"http://www.worldbellydancefestival.com/WBDF-contact-cn";
}else{
    urlString = @"http://www.worldbellydancefestival.com/WBDF-contact";
}
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLRequest *urlrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[_Contact loadRequest:urlrequest];
```

}

Hi, thanks for your reply, I don’t know how to add a url into my localised.string file, should I directly insert the cn url into the “ IBUINavigationItem”? could you please show me how? Many thanks.

```
/* Class = "IBUINavigationItem"; title = "Contact"; ObjectID = "f7r-UW-c2m"; */

"f7r-UW-c2m.title" = "联系我们”;

/* Class = "IBUILabel"; text = "Contact"; ObjectID = "BoC-hp-Vrj"; */
"BoC-hp-Vrj.text" = "联系我们";
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, In my point, the content of User Agent from the webkit in UIWebView or WKWebView contains the language environment.So, my suggestion is server can execute different forwarding operations according to the so-called UA information from iOS client that passed from url,what you need is only pass different value such as @"http://helloworld.com?language=en" depending on the language environment.Good luck!